# HighChart using min max on logarithmic axis lack minor ticks grid

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highchart to display graphs with logarithmic axis. I really need to set min and max values precisely on the yAxis.

unfortunately if my max value is not on a tick it won't display minorTrickGrid as expected.

seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3jXx/2/)

expected result should be like [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/a3jXx/5/) but without the tick '**1000**'. With the max being exactly **999**

the key line is `max : 1000` which allows minor grid lines to be displayed. but my problem is I need to set the max to 999 (`max : 999`) which makes the minor grid strange.

the question is :  is this a bug or is there a way to display minor grid lines in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of the 1k label, you can keep the max:1000, but add a custom formatter function like this:

```
yAxis: {
            endOnTick: false,
            type: 'logarithmic',
            minorTickInterval: 0.1,
            min: 1,
            max: 1000,
            labels:{
                formatter:function() {
                    if (this.value==1000) {
                        return "";
                    } else {
                        return this.value;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hA9yF/

This still won't work if you set max:999, but may be a suitable work-around for you.

Comment: as I said, this is not the point : I don't mind about displaying 1k or 1000, what I want is to have the max value being 999 and display the minor tick grid, both at the same time.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use labels formatter (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter)  and highcharts.numberFormat() (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat()) which allows to return customised number figure.

http://jsfiddle.net/a3jXx/5/

```
labels:{
                formatter:function(){

                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value,0);

                }
            }
```

Comment: sorry, I don't mind about displaying 1k or 1000, what I want is to have the max value being 999 and display the minor tick grid, both at the same time.

Comment: So you can define it by tickPositioner which allows to define customised dynamic ticks: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner